# How to connect each person in a table to another table respectively in a database?

Tags: mysql

im currently building an attendance system where only a specific person (A) can log in and take the attendance of the another person (B,C,D) . let me give an example, [image: this is the database example]

As you can see,there are 3 tables there, `login_user`, `school_A (CGA)` and `school_B (AES)`. 
The person in the `login_user` table is the person (A) that i mentioned above.

The other two tables are entirely different school which is `school_A (CGA)` and `school_B (AES)`.
As you can see `user_ID` named `CGA001` and `CGA002` are in the `school_A (CGA)` table and `AES001` is in the `school_B (AES)` table.
The `user_ID`column in the `school_A (CGA)` and `school_B(AES)` tables which is `CK11213`, `CK11214`, `AK4143`, `AK4144` and `AK4145` are the students in each school - person (B,C,D).

My problem right now, how to connect the each person in `login_user` table to the `school_A (CGA)` and `school_B (AES)` tables respectively which means `user_ID` that have `CGAxxx` will connect to `school_A (CGA)` and whose have `AESxxx` will connect to `school_B (AES)`.

Im using `php`,`mysqli` and `html` in the making process.
And yes, im a total beginner.

i already researched and find nothing that can solve my problem, maybe i overlooked at them.

If you have any suggestion or alternative to change my table structure, please tell me. i will accept everything.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Beginner but if you know about foreign keys than you can see both B and A tables have user_id meaning both are connected to users

Comment: okay, i will give it a try. thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A couple of issues to address first:

1) Looks like users john, mary, and olivia don't have attendance taken, therefore, they don't belong in tables `school_A` and `school_B` which seems to be the attendance for each school. Instead, add a field to table `login_user` showing which school the user is responsible for, `school_ID`.

2) The tables `school_A` and `school_B` hold the same data, `user_ID`, `name`, and `attendance`, and only exist to "sort" the students by school. If a student switches schools then they must be removed from one and added to the other. Instead, merge the two tables into one table, `attendance`, adding a field to identify which schhol they attend, `school_ID`. Then add a new table `school` with fields `school_ID` and `name`, possible third field `school_code` for the "CGA" and "AES" in your sample data, if that's an important piece of information. This simplifies moving students from one school to another, and allows adding new schools without having to and a new table every time.

This gives you this database structure:

[image]

To select the people (B,C,D) a specific person (A) can log in and take the attendance of use

```
SELECT login_user.name AS taker, school_code, attendance.name AS student FROM login_user LEFT JOIN school USING (school_ID) LEFT JOIN attendance USING (school_ID) WHERE login_user.user_ID='CGA002';
```

To create a list of all people able to log in and take attendance, connected to who they can take attendance for, based on a single school (could be more than one attendance taker), use

```
SELECT login_user.name AS taker, school_code, attendance.name AS student FROM login_user LEFT JOIN school USING (school_ID) LEFT JOIN attendance USING (school_ID) WHERE school_code='CGA';
```

To create a complete list of all attendance takers, connected to whom they can take attendance for, use

```
SELECT login_user.name AS taker, school_code, attendance.name AS student FROM login_user LEFT JOIN school USING (school_ID) LEFT JOIN attendance USING (school_ID) ORDER BY school_code;
```

When you add a third, or fourth, school, you only need to add the data to the `school` table and insert the new people into the *one* table they belong in, either `login_user`, or `attendance` with the school_ID they are associated with.

Of course the names of fields in the tables should be a bit more specific, and I imagine your tables will have more fields than what was given. in the `login_user` table, it should be something like: `login_ID`, `school_ID`, `login_name`, `pass`. The `attendance` table something like: `student_ID`, `school_ID`, `student_name`, `attendance`.

The [MySQL online manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/) is a good place to find all the details.

Comment: okay. great suggestion. i think i will create the database based on your suggestion. by the way, who is the `taker` that you mentioned in `SELECT` command? name or what is it? im sorry if this is a silly question, but i need to know.

Comment: `taker` in the query is an 'alias' given to the `name` field of the `login_user` table. That's because all the tables you started with had `name` in them, and a list of names without knowing which is which won't make much sense. I chose the word `taker` since it's the person taking attendance. Makes sense if it's an instructor, but the question never said. Similarly, the `attendance` table, `name` field was given the alias of `student`. When planning your tables, thinking about how the filed names will be used helps avoid that problem. Pick names that work without being the same.

Comment: alright. now i understand. thanks a lot for your database structure and advice. now i can continue finishing my database. Thanks again.

Comment: im sorry. Based on your given database structure, does the `school_ID` in the table `attendance` refers to the `school_ID` in the `login_user` table?       Does that mean the `attendance` table will also have a _null_ value? Because the teachers 's id which is `school_ID` in the `attendance` table.

Comment: Or did i misunderstand it. If it is, please explain to me.

Comment: The teachers are not in the `attendance` table at all, only students. The `school_ID` in `attendance` table shows which school the student attends, and is a foreign key in that table. The `school_ID` in the `login_user` table shows which school the teacher works at and is a "foreign key"also.  In the `school` table where the primary key is `school_ID`, is what the foreign keys link to. The foreign key in one table does not _have_ to be the same name as the primary key in the other table, but it makes it obvious that they are related when they _do_ have the same name.

Comment: I'm sorry. But the `SELECT login_user.name AS taker, school_code, attendance.name AS student FROM login_user LEFT JOIN school USING (school_ID) LEFT JOIN attendance USING (school_ID) ORDER BY school_code;` that you had given above is just to show the list only right?
So, I would like to know on how to make this command as 'permanent' so that the teacher that logged on will only see his/her school's student only? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM login_users lg LEFT JOIN school_A a ON lg.user_ID = a.user_ID
LEFT JOIN school_B b ON lg.user_ID=b.user_ID
```

This will select users with his respective data from each table

Comment: okay. Let say, i add one more table which is school_C (GHK). so i need to re-enter the command above again?

Comment: what command? the sql is needed to either select, insert, update or delete the data from the database. So if you want to retrieve data you need to write sql

Comment: the command that you wrote above. like this `SELECT * FROM login_users lg LEFT JOIN school_A a ON lg.user_ID = a.user_ID
LEFT JOIN school_B b ON lg.user_ID=b.user_ID`